# JS: How to create an object with a function

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose i wanted to create an object using JS and then have a function call from inside it, i read this line of code should work but it hasn't.

```
var college = {name: “College Of West Anglia”, pupils:1200, location1: “Kings Lynn”, location2:”Wisbech”, location3:”Cambridge”, fulladdress: function(){ 
return this.name + " " + this.location1}};
```

It comes up with a "token error".

Comment: The problem isn't the functions, it's the quotes. Use normal, straight up-and-down quotes (`"`), not fancy quotes (`“`).

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future.

Comment: Word processors make *terrible* IDEs.